# Check if row used by another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `emails_accounts` with a structure like this:

```
╔════╦═════════════════════╦══════════════╗
║ id ║        email        ║ description  ║
╠════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║ test@gmail.com      ║ Lorem        ║
║  2 ║ example@example.com ║ Ipsum        ║
║  3 ║ test@example.com    ║ Dolor        ║
║  4 ║ retail@example.com  ║ Sit Amet     ║
╚════╩═════════════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Each email is **unique**.

And a second table `email_templates` with a structure similiar to this:

```
╔════╦══════════════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ email_title      ║ email_from ║ email_to ║
╠════╬══════════════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║ 1  ║ Test title       ║ 1          ║ 3        ║
║ 2  ║ Second title     ║ 2          ║ 3        ║
║ 3  ║ Some title       ║ 1          ║ 1        ║
╚════╩══════════════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

`email_to` and `email_from` can be different, but they can be the same (as shown in the example).

What I want to achieve is to create a SQL query which gives me **ALL** accounts from the table `emails_accounts` but with additional information - how much every account is used in a table `email_templates` (it needs to check `email_from` and `email_to`).

I know it shouldn't be too hard, but so far I didn't manage to get the results right.
My code at the moment is:

```
SELECT acc.* , COUNT( temp.id ) 
FROM emails_accounts acc
LEFT JOIN email_templates temp ON acc.id = temp.email_from
GROUP BY acc.email
```

But I would like to have both `email_from` and `email_to` counted.

I tried also this:

```
SELECT acc . * , COUNT( temp.id ) + COUNT( temp2.id ) AS count
FROM emails_accounts acc
LEFT JOIN email_templates temp ON acc.id = temp.email_from
LEFT JOIN email_templates temp2 ON acc.id = temp2.email_to
GROUP BY acc.email
```

But it gives too many results.

---

EDIT: I've [created a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/984c2/1) with correct answer included - thanks to [jaczes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2564772/jaczes).

Comment: Think about your boundary conditions before posting your question. 1) Is email_from <> email_to in each record? 2) Are email adresses unique in emails_accounts, or can they occur in multiple records?

Comment: Each email is unique in `emails_accounts` but email_from might be different from email_to as shown in example

Comment: Update your question instead of hiding essential information in the comments. And you're not explicitly answering my 1st question. What we can infer from your "might" comment is that the answer is "No, they can be the same".

Comment: I don't really get why are you getting so pissed off. I was editing, didn't manage to edit so fast, now it's all included in the question. And second thing - I don't understand why in your opinion I didn't answer your question explicitly. I told you it "might" be different, which exactly means it can be different, but it can be the same. What is so disorienting in this statement? And I think the example data shows perfectly, what I just said.

Comment: I'm not pissed off, don't worry, and have no intention of offending you. I'm just advocating for clarity in questions and doing that without mincing words. When you say "might be different" the statement is: "they are usually the same, but occassionally they can differ." That is different from "They are usually different, but occasionally they are equal." So instead of directly answering the "are adresses unique?" you take the roundabout route answering and leave us to conclude "no". That's it.

Comment: Sorry then, didn't mean it like that. Really thought it was clear. By the way, how these two situation can make difference? I'm talking about: "they are usually the same, but occassionally they can differ." and "They are usually different, but occasionally they are equal."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about that ?

```
SELECT ea.*,efrom, eto, ifnull(efrom,0)+ifnull(eto,0) as count 
from emails_accounts ea 
LEFT JOIN 
(select email_from,count(email_from) as efrom 
  FROM email_templates group by email_from)
as e_from on ea.id=email_from
LEFT JOIN 
(select email_to, count(email_to) as eto 
  FROM email_templates group by email_to)
as e_to on ea.id=email_to
```

Comment: It seems it works fine this way :) I was very close to that answer when I looked at the Declan_K union solution, but you were faster. I even created a sql fiddle to the solution. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Use the following UNION as a virtual table in your 1st query

```
select  email_from  as email_id
        ,Count(*)   as template_count
from    email_templates
group by
        email_from
union        
select  email_to    as email_id
        ,Count(*)   as template_count
from    email_templates
group by
        email_to
```

Comment: Seems like a good approach. Although it doubles the keys. How can I JOIN these two tables into one so the keys remain unique for each summed usage of mails?